# Spring Data Redis: What is the difference between the two ways to obtain ZSetOperations?

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data

**First example**

```
@Resource
StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;
ZSetOperations<String, String> zSetOps = stringRedisTemplate.opsForZSet();
```

**Second example**

```
@Resource(name="stringRedisTemplate")
private ZSetOperations<String, String> zSetOps;
```

Can anyone explain the difference between the first and second and whether the second one is working like first one?

Comment: In the 1st, java infers name and in the 2nd you supplied the name.

Comment: Apparently they both have RedisOperations interface in common.